# How do I reference a jar file from an External Library using relative path in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, apache-spark, gradle, intellij-idea

In my External Libraries directory, I can find my jars - for example hppc-0.8.1.jar (arbitrarily chosen).

[External Library jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTUlb.png)

I want to reference this jar in order to provide it to a SparkSession in the configuration. However, I can only reference it with the absolute path and this is a problem as my teammates and I share a repo.

How can I reference this jar so that I don't have to use an absolute path and have merge conflicts every time we push? The commented line is my teammates path whereas the included path is my path.

````
                    .appName(appName)
                    .master("spark://" + sparkHost + ":" + sparkPort)
                    .config("es.nodes", esHost)
                    .config("es.port", esPort)
                    .config("es.index.auto.create", "true")
                    .config("es.read.metadata", true)
                    .config("es.mapping.date.rich", false)
                    .config("es.read.field.as.array.include", "OPUpdatedField")
//                    .config("spark.jars", "/Users/teammate/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/7.7.1/683ff752340d4f7466efba129cd8a8d62fe12093/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.7.1.jar")
                    .config("spark.jars", "/Users/myname/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/7.7.1/683ff752340d4f7466efba129cd8a8d62fe12093/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.7.1.jar")
                    .getOrCreate()```
````

Answer (score 0):

If the library is inside the project root, the path will be stored relatively using the placeholder.

In the library `.xml` file or in the project `.iml` file you'll see something like this:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="libs">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/libs/json.jar!/" />
```

For the paths outside of the project that can be anywhere on the system consider using the [path variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/absolute-path-variables.html).